# Локализация в GWT

Tags: gwt

К примеру, у меня есть файлы ресурсов

```
ru.properties
en.properties
kz.properties
```

в папке

```
tomcat/webapps/ROOT/resources/..
```

содержимое файлой:

```
title=Моя страница
```

Каким образом можно в ГВТ обратится к этим ресурам + после компиляции были созданы кешируемые js с каждой локализацией.

Хотел бы сделать так:

```
onModuleLoad() {
   Window.alert(MessageBundle.get("title"));   
)}
```

или так:

```
onModuleLoad() {
   MessageBundle.load("ru", new OnLoad(){   
       onload() { 
           Window.alert(MessageBundle.get("title"));
       }
   }
)}
```

спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да прочтите же [документацию](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideI18nAndA11y.html) наконец. Там про всё написано. И про статическую локализацию, и про Localizable, и про [Dictionary](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html)

Ещё можно нагуглить кучу примеров, [вот например](http://www.techhui.com/profiles/blogs/localization-in-gwt-using).

Comment: Везде подходы разные. У меня конкретный. Документацию читать можно... много и долго. А посмотреть пример, который решает задачу, гораздо эффективнее.